# Are custom page templates being used to get this permalink structure

Tags: permalinks, urls

There's a website which has page URL's such as `http://www.example.com/states/new-york/`

If I go to `http://www.example.com/states/` I get a 404 error.

The site also has `http://www.example.com/category/some-category-name/` and `http://www.example.com/tag/a-tag/`

So clearly they haven't modified their permalink category and tag bases. Or customized them. I'm thinking they created custom page templates and pages who's parent is a a page called `states` to get the permalink `/states/new-york/` but then why would going to `/states/` throw a 404?

Can a link structure like this be created any other way?

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking if you could do something like this:

```
/states/%postname%/
```

In the permalink structure? As to why it's giving back a 404 I'm not sure.

Comment: I know I can add `/states/` to the custom permalink structure but that would apply it site wide. This site only has it on a few URLs which is why I think they setup custom page templates with wp_list_categories to make it function like a category page and /states/ in the URL being the parent page.

Comment: It wouldn't necessarily apply it site wide, using [this website](http://www.bravialife.com/) as an example (a website I've worked on), I used **/bravia-blog/%postname%/** and you will notice only on the blog page does it display **/bravia-blog/**.